# Alias to a function template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, alias

```
int f1(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
int f2(int a, int b) { return a*b; }

template <typename F> void foo(int i, int j)
{
 // do some processing before
 F(i,j);  
 // do some processing after 
}
```

I want to make an alias to a specialization of foo like this:

```
constexpr auto foo1 = &foo<f1>;
constexpr auto foo2 = &foo<f2>;
```

and call the function like this: `foo1(1,2);foo2(1,2);`
Any way to achieve this in C++? Thanks!

---

**Edit:**
foo() is not a wrapper of f1, it is a function that calls f1 or f2. I need to do something extra before and after the call. F is a functor and I want a 'short cut' to the specialization of foo. **The code above is kind of psuedo code.**

Comment: Read about [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how can std::bind help to solve my problem?

Comment: `auto foo1 = std::bind(f1, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2); foo1(1, 2);` Isn't it something like that you wanted?

Comment: `F` is a type, not a value. What're you actually trying to do that isn't just `auto foo1 = f1`?

Comment: F is a *type*, not some object, so `F(i,j)` makes no sense.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks but that's an alias to f1, not foo, so it's not what I want.

Comment: What I'm saying is that your wrapper function `foo` is a poor reimplementation of `std::bind`, and you don't really need `foo` since the functionality is already in the standard library. Don't attempt to (poorly) reimplement the wheel and all that. Maybe you can explain and elaborate what problem you are *actually* trying to solve with a function like `foo` and "aliases"? Please [read about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: "that's an alias to f1, not foo, so it's not what I want" ... but your example looks like this is just what you want. It is not clear what the template is supposed to be good for if anyhoy you want to call `f1` and `f2` via seperate aliases

Comment: now it is a bit more clear ;)

Comment: guys, I have edited the question. to clarify, foo() is not a wrapper of f1, it is a function that calls f1 or f2. I need to do something extra before and after the call. F is a functor and I want a 'short cut' to the specialization of foo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some good approaches in the comments: std::bind, using a lambda, passing an instance of `F` into the function, so I'll provide an alternative.

If the function type that you will pass into `foo` will always be `int(int, int)`, then you make the template parameter be a non-type template parameter, and then instantiate it with one of your functions:

```
int f1(int a, int b) { std::cout<<"f1\n"; return a+b; }
int f2(int a, int b) { std::cout<<"f2\n"; return a*b; }

template <int(*F)(int, int)> 
void foo(int i, int j)
{
    F(i,j);   
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr auto foo1 = foo<f1>;
    constexpr auto foo2 = foo<f2>;
    foo1(1,2);
    foo2(1,2);
}
```

Output:

> f1 
>   f2

The trick we're doing here is that we're making the template parameter be a reference to a function, which is hacky but legal AFAIK.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25b92211341ebbed)

Comment: You're hardcoding a dependency on `f1`, why not use e.g. `template<int(*F)(int, int)>` instead?

Comment: @Joachim: Yeah that would be safer. I was just lazy.

Comment: although decltype... bit looks a bit hacky as you said, this is nice & simple.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578023/4573247) is spot-on for the OP's request. To complement that answer: an alternative method could be letting the `int(int, int)` function pointer be an additional argument to the function (in which case we needn't use template techniques), and use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to set up the different default case functions to be used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int f1(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
int f2(int a, int b) { return a*b; }
int f3(int a, int b) { return a-b; }

void foo(int i, int j, int (*f)(int, int)) {
  // do some processing before
  std::cout << f(i, j) << std::endl;
  // do some processing after
}

int main()
{
  const auto foo1 = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, &f1);
  const auto foo2 = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, &f2);

  foo1(5, 5);     // 10
  foo2(5, 5);     // 25
  foo(5, 5, &f3); // 0

  return 0;
}
```

A variation of the above could allow using function wrappers ([`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)) to store the help functions as values, in cases these would, for some reason, risk going out of scope prior to the caller objects (`foo1`, `foo2`, ...).

```
void foo(int i, int j, const std::function<int(int, int)> f) { /* ... */ }

// ...

const auto foo1 = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, f1);
const auto foo2 = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, f2);
```